# Google hreflang usage

Tags: seo

Does this look right? SEO expert said that this is the way to do it, but for some reason I think it could be wrong because we are using the same url for different hreflang

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-bn' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-cn' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-hk' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-in' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-id' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-jp' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-kr' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-my' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-pk' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-ph' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-sg' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-lk' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-tw' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang='en-th' href='http://www.xxx.com/gsa'/>
```

Would Google penalize a website for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think they might. If you see **[this post on the Google Webmaster Central Blog](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/12/new-markup-for-multilingual-content.html)**, they recommend something like the following:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://www.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-ES" href="http://es-es.example.com/" />
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-MX" href="http://es-mx.example.com/" /> 
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://en.example.com/" />
```

Google says:

> If you specify a regional subtag, we’ll assume that you want to target
>   that region. Keep in mind that all of these annotations are to be used
>   on a per-URL basis. You should take care to use the specific URL, not
>   the homepage, for both of these link elements.

---

Also, from their **[guidelines here](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2010/09/unifying-content-under-multilingual.html)**,

> Have one URL associated with one piece of content. We recommend
>   **against using the same URL** for multiple languages, such as serving
>   both French and English versions on example.com/page.html based on
>   user information (IP address, Accept-Language HTTP header).
>   <sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

If you aren't redirecting the user to **different sites** based on language/localization, you might get penalized for it, as Google explicitly recommends against it.

Comment: @Igor-G [**This page**](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2010/09/unifying-content-under-multilingual.html) has a little more detail. It says `Have one URL associated with one piece of content. We recommend against using the same URL for multiple languages`