# SEO - Mutli international domains vs one site?

Tags: seo

**MAIN (US/UK)**

```
http://www.gc.com/
http://www.gc.com/categorys
http://www.gc.com/categorys/products
http://www.gc.com/categorys/products/item-1
```

**PL (Polish)**

```
http://www.gc.pl/
http://www.gc.pl/categorys
http://www.gc.pl/categorys/products
http://www.gc.pl/categorys/products/item-1
```

**DE (Deutsch)**

```
http://www.gc.de/
http://www.gc.de/categorys
http://www.gc.de/categorys/products
http://www.gc.de/categorys/products/item-1
```

We have domains for over 20 countries so you get the point.

## What is the best solution for SEO?

1. Keep the multi domain option, and just add Canonical meta to the .com for international URL
2. Keep the store to .com and all the URLS to .com - when the customer lands on any page with a new session offer them currency and language options and then update the system to reflect - but still use the same URLs

Our Ecommerce platform allows us to have multiple stores. Alternative we can have one store, with multiple languages and multiple currencies. The prime question is about the SEO and flagging of having all these domains listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use canonical across languages.  Rather you should use link tags with hreflang attributes.

Because you have an ecommerce store that will need to deal with prices, currencies, and shipping, you should do geographic targeting.   You should have one site per country and make sure that Google gets the geographic targeting of each correct using Webmaster Tools.

I'm not sure what the difference between multiple stores and a single store with multiple languages is.  For SEO, there are several ways of setting it up, but you need to have separate URLs for each country.  They can either be different domains, different sub-domains, or different folders.  Here is a [more in depth answer about setting up international URLs for SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/44289/14543).

Comment: Thanks, I also saw this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369739/google-hreflang-usage